# Why excel is not hiding my shape?

Tags: excel, vba, macros, hide, basic

I'm using this code below...

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As Long)
Sub blink()
    Sleep 500
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("the_shape").Visible = False
    Sleep 500
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("the_shape").Visible = True
End Sub
```

am I missing something?

Comment: Full sentences are much easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is pretty strange.  Adding `DoEvents` resolved the problem.  I'm guessing that `Sleep` is pausing the thread before Excel has a chance to hide the shape.

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As Long)

Sub blink()
    Sleep 500
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("the_shape").Visible = False
    DoEvents
    Sleep 500
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("the_shape").Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, pretty strange, But your answer worked.